# Git Diff is not working on EC2 Windows server 2012

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running following git command to get latest committed change. It is working fine on my machine Windows 2010 but not working on EC2 windows server 2012

```
git diff --name-only @~..@
```

I am getting following error while running this command on EC2 Windows server instance -

```
C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\workspace\Build Bitbucket>git diff --name-only @~..@
fatal: ambiguous argument '@~..@': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

May anyone suggest what is the issue and how can i get latest commit changes in EC2 windows server?

I am using Git 1.9.9 version.

`git diff --name-only HEAD~..HEAD` also giving the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You git version is perhaps a bit old and doesn't understand `@` as `HEAD`. Use `HEAD` instead:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~..HEAD
```

Comment: This is also not working. I am using git 1.9.9. I am getting same error in HEAD~..HEAD

Comment: Do you have a file named HEAD? Try `git diff --name-only HEAD~..HEAD --`

Comment: Results are as follows- C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\workspace\Build Bitbucket>git diff --name-only HEAD~..HEAD --
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD~..HEAD'

C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\workspace\Build Bitbucket>git diff --name-only HEAD~..HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the wor
king tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'